# Approximating $e^{-2x}$ using a linear combination of Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: numerical-methods, least-squares, chebyshev-polynomials

I've been asked to find the coefficients $c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3$ for $P_4(x) = c_0 \, T_0(x) + c_1 \, T_1(x) + c_2 \, T_2(x) +c_3 \, T_3(x)$ given $f(x) = e^{-2x}$, where $T_n(x)$ are Chebyshev polynomials.

I've tried to calculate the coefficients, but result in much larger than expected error. Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Is the interval $[-1,1]$? For what norm is the error to be minimized?

Comment: Please show your calculations.

Comment: Yes, the interval is [-1,1]. I don't have a set error, just need to find the maximum error, but the results I'm getting put the maximum error around 3 which seems like it must be way off.

Comment: You get different best approximations for different errors, the most usual choices are the $L^1$ norm, the $L^2$ norm and the supremum norm. If the topic is not min-maxing  with the Remez algorithm, then the $L^2$ norm is most likely.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_{-1}^{+1}\Big[e^{-2x}-\sum_{k=0}^n c_k\,T_k(x)\Big]^2\,dx$$ which is quite simple.

Minimize $\Phi_n$ setting to zero its derivatives with respect to the $c_k$ to obtain these coefficients.

For $n=3$ the largest absolute error should be $0.23$ at $x=-1$.

You probably have some mistake in the calculations.